# How to plot a graph in gnuplot without specifying the coordinates of vertices?

Tags: graph, gnuplot, graph-theory

I want to use gnuplot to plot relations rather than the exact coordinates.
Something like Igraph in R where I can do A->B without specifying the coordinates in space. I am using a [gnuplot script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447683/how-to-plot-a-tree-graph-web-with-weighted-edges-in-gnuplot) specified on other SO answers inside the system call.

I want to integrate it with my ocaml compiler inside LLVM. If there are any suggestions on that as well, please let me know.

Thank you so much.

Comment: http://www.graphviz.org/ may be a better tool for this task.

Comment: Have you considered using dot/graphViz? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: why is C tagged here?

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing graphs is a large and interesting field. And as @eush77 mentioned, [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a dedicated tool for this type of task.

Although, you could do something with gnuplot. There is a relatively simple algorithm which is based on attracting and repelling forces between vertices. Details can be found e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3011.pdf).

First, the script places the vertices at random coordinates and then iterates to a final state (however, which is not always optimal).
You need to play with the constants `c1,c2,c3,c4`.
The example below used the gif terminal to visualize the iterations. If you are only interested in the final result, use another terminal and move the `replot` after the loop.
The script below is a starting point and can certainly be improved. Suggestions and comments are welcome.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0, because of the use of arrays)

```
### plotting optimized graph
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# ID   PointColor
  1    0xffaaaa
  2    0xaaffaa
  3    0xaaaaff
  4    0xffaaff
  5    0xffffaa
  6    0xaaffff
 73    0xcccccc
  A    0xcccccc
 XY    0xcccccc
  0    0xffffff
  G    0xffffff


# ID1 ID2   LineColor
  1   4     0x0000ff
  2   4     0x000000
  3   4     0x00ff00
  5   4     0x000000
  6   5     0xff0000
 73   3     0xcccccc
 73   4     0xcccccc
 73   5     0xcccccc
  A   2     0xcccccc
  A   3     0xcccccc
  2   1     0xcccccc
 XY   4     0xcccccc
 XY   6     0xcccccc
  0   2     0xcccccc
  0   XY    0xcccccc
  G   0     0xcccccc
  G   A     0xcccccc
EOD

stats $Data u (column(-2)==0?Nv=int($0+1):Ne=int($0+1)) nooutput  # get number of vertices and edges
array Vx[Nv]
array Vy[Nv]
array Vt[Nv]
array Vc[Nv]
stats $Data index 0 u (i=int($0)+1, Vt[i]=strcol(1), Vx[i]=rand(0)*10, Vy[i]=rand(0)*10, \
                       Vc[i]=int($2)) nooutput     # random placement of vertices
Vidx(s) = sum[_i=1:|Vx|] ( Vt[_i] eq s ? _i : 0)   # get index via lookup of vertex "name"

array E0[Ne]
array E1[Ne]
array Ec[Ne]
stats $Data index 1 u (i=int($0)+1, E0[i]=Vidx(strcol(1)), E1[i]=Vidx(strcol(2)), \
           Ec[i]=int($3) ) nooutput    # get edge point indices

set size ratio 1
set key noautotitle
set offsets 0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
unset border
unset tics

set term gif animate delay 20
set output "SO43843240.gif"

plot E0 u (i=int($0+1), x0=Vx[E0[i]]):(y0=Vy[E0[i]]):(Vx[E1[i]]-x0):(Vy[E1[i]]-y0): \
          (Ec[i]) w vec lw 2 lc rgb var nohead, \
     Vx u (i=int($0+1),Vx[i]):(Vy[i]):(Vc[i]) w p pt 7 ps 6 lc rgb var, \
     '' u (i=int($0+1),Vx[i]):(Vy[i]) w p pt 6 ps 6 lc rgb "black", \
     '' u (i=int($0+1),Vx[i]):(Vy[i]):(Vt[i]) w labels

# parameters for force 
c1 = 2
c2 = 1
c3 = 1
c4 = 0.2
fs(d) = c1*log(d/c2)   # force spring attracting/repelling
fr(d) = c3/d           # force repelling

dV(i,j) = sqrt((Vx[j]-Vx[i])**2 + (Vy[j]-Vy[i])**2)
set angle degrees
a(i,j) = atan2(Vy[j]-Vy[i], Vx[j]-Vx[i])

array Fx[Nv]   # force in x
array Fy[Nv]   # force in y

do for [n=1:500] {
    set label 1 at screen 1.0,0.97 sprintf("Iteration: % 4d",n) right

    # repelling forces
    do for [i=1:Nv] {
        Fx[i] = Fy[i] = 0   # initialize
        do for [j=1:Nv] {
            if (i!=j) {
                f0 = fr(dV(i,j))
                a0 = a(i,j)
                Fx[i] = Fx[i] - f0*cos(a0)
                Fy[i] = Fy[i] - f0*sin(a0)
            }
        }
    }
    # spring forces
    do for [n=1:Ne] {
        i = E0[n]
        j = E1[n]
        f0 = fs(dV(i,j))
        a0 = a(i,j)
        Fx[i]=Fx[i]+f0*cos(a0)
        Fy[i]=Fy[i]+f0*sin(a0)
        Fx[j]=Fx[j]-f0*cos(a0)
        Fy[j]=Fy[j]-f0*sin(a0)
    }
    # add displacement
    do for [i=1:Nv] {
        Vx[i] = Vx[i] + c4*Fx[i]
        Vy[i] = Vy[i] + c4*Fy[i]
    }
    stats Fy u 2 nooutput                   # get maximum change y
    if (abs(c4*STATS_max)<0.005) { break }  # exit loop when max. y-displacement below threshold
    replot
}

set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** (animation from gif terminal)

[image]