# How to plot network by gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a list of more than 100 points. I'd like to plot a figure like this picture. The lines connect any two points whose distance is less than 3.

```
1.53   2.40
5.39   3.02
4.35   1.29
9.58   8.34
6.59   1.45
3.44   3.45
7.22   0.43
0.23   8.09
4.38   3.49
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1237026/Simple-MLP-Backpropagation-Artificial-Neural-Netwo
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to check every point against every other point whether the distance is less than your threshold. So, create a table with all these points, the vector between them and plot them `with vectors`. The following example creates some random points with random sizes and random colors.

**Code:**

```
### Plot connections between points which are closer than a threshold
reset session
set size square

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    myColors = "0xe71840 0x4d76c3 0xf04092 0x47c0ad 0xf58b1e 0xe6eb18 0x59268e 0x36b64c"
    myColor(n) = int(word(myColors,n))
    do for [i=1:100] {
        print sprintf("%g %g %g %d", rand(0), rand(0), rand(0)*2+1, myColor(int(rand(0)*8)+1))
    }
set print

d(x1,y1,x2,y2) = sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
myDist = 0.2

set print $Connect
    do for [i=1:|$Data|-1] {
        x1=real(word($Data[i],1))
        y1=real(word($Data[i],2))
        do for [j=i+1:|$Data|] {
            x2=real(word($Data[j],1))
            y2=real(word($Data[j],2))
            if (d(x1,y1,x2,y2)<myDist) { print sprintf("%g %g %g %g", x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1) }
        }
    }
set print

set key noautotitle
plot $Connect u 1:2:3:4 w vec lc "grey" nohead, \
        $Data u 1:2:3:4 w p pt 7 ps var lc rgb var
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The principles of these posts about Delaunay triangulation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68507661), 
Voronoi diagrams (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73936869) and 
optimizing node graphs (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74576116)
might lead (with some modifications) to similar results.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify how to choose the node size or color. I show an example using a constant pointsize and taking the color from sequential linetypes

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]$DATA << EOD
1.53   2.40
5.39   3.02
4.35   1.29
9.58   8.34
6.59   1.45
3.44   3.45
7.22   0.43
0.23   8.09
4.38   3.49
EOD

N = |$DATA|

do for [i=1:N] {
    do for [j=i+1:N] {
        x0 = real(word($DATA[i],1))
        y0 = real(word($DATA[i],2))
        x1 = real(word($DATA[j],1))
        y1 = real(word($DATA[j],2))
        if ((x1-x0)**2 + (y1-y0)**2 <= 9) {
            set arrow from x0,y0 to x1,y1 nohead
        }
    }
}
unset border
unset tics
unset key
set pointsize 3

plot $DATA using 1:2:0 with points pt 7 lc variable
```

[image]