# Draw process tree with gnuplot

Tags: ubuntu, process, gnuplot

similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406346/how-to-plot-tree-graph-web-data-on-gnuplot)
I want to draw process tree where a PID is given, I should be able to draw that process and its children as a tree. However, I want to preserve parent children relationship between nodes/edges. What I mean is, any two children should not have edge between. Coordinates actually do not matter. Also, I am open for other drawing tool options. I tried the accepted answer of mentioned question but it links all nodes.

Any kind of suggestion/help would make my day.

Note: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: how does your data look like? please show some example data. What have you tried with gnuplot so far? Please show your code or at least a hand sketch how you would like to have the graph.

Comment: as data, I only have pid of the parent and pids of the children. I do not have any code of gnuplot because I do not know where to start. As a visualization, you can refer to the link given.

Comment: `graphviz` may be the tool you are looking for. You could try [here](http://www.webgraphviz.com/)

Comment: can it be used in C? or in linux shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't give too many details what you have and what you exactly want. So I assume something. Certainly, room for improvements. To learn more about plotting styles, in gnuplot console check `help points`, `help vectors`, `help labels`.

**Code:**

```
### drawing a simple tree
reset session

$Children <<EOD
23
34
45
56
67
78
EOD

$Parent <<EOD
123
EOD

unset border
unset tics
Size = 8
set offsets 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2

plot $Children u (Last=$0):(1):1 w labels not, \
     '' u 0:(1):(Last/2-$0):(1) w vectors nohead lc rgb "black" notitle, \
     '' u 0:(1):(Size) w p pt 7 ps var lc rgb "yellow" not, \
     '' u 0:(1):1 w labels not, \
     $Parent u (Last/2):(2):(Size) w p pt 7 ps var lc rgb "light-grey" not, \
     '' u (Last/2):(2):1 w labels center not
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Actually, you can do a bit more complex tree diagrams with gnuplot. Fortunately, gnuplot allows for recursive functions.

The input consists out of 3 columns without header.
Each ID has only one parent, except one which is the top node. An ID can have several children.

Prerequisites:

- Column 1 contains unique integer ID numbers
- Column 2 contains the parent ID of the child ID in column 1, or `NaN` for the top node.
- Column 3 names of labels of the nodes

Improvements are welcome.

**Code:** (actually some "nonsense" tree)

```
### tree diagram with gnuplot
reset session

#ID  Parent   Name
$Data <<EOD
   1    NaN   Ant
   2      1   Ape
   3      1   Ass
   4      2   Bat
   5      2   Bee
   6      2   Cat
   7      3   Cod
   8      3   Cow
   9      3   Dog
  10      7   Eel
  11      7   Elk
  12      7   Emu
  13      9   Fly
  14      9   Fox
  15      4   Gnu
  16      1   Hen
  17     16   Hog
  18     12   Jay
  19     12   Owl
  20     15   Pig
  21     15   Pug
  22     12   Ram
  23     14   Rat
  24     12   Sow
  25      7   Yak
EOD

# put datablock into strings
IDs = Parents = Names = ''
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (IDs = IDs.strcol(1).' '): \
                 (Parents = Parents.strcol(2).' '): \
                 (Names = Names.strcol(3).' ') w table
unset table

# Top node has no parent ID 'NaN'
Start(n) = int(sum [i=1:words(Parents)] (word(Parents,i) eq 'NaN' ? int(word(IDs,i)) : 0))

# get list index by ID
ItemIdx(s,n) = n == n ? (tmp=NaN, sum [i=1:words(s)] ((word(s,i)) == n ? (tmp=i,0) : 0), tmp) : NaN

# get parent of ID n
Parent(n) = word(Parents,ItemIdx(IDs,n))

# get level of ID n, recursive function
Level(n) = n == n ? Parent(n)>0 ? Level(Parent(n))-1 : 0 : NaN

# get number of children of ID n
ChildCount(n) = int(sum [i=1:words(Parents)] (word(Parents,i)==n))

# Create child list of ID n
ChildList(n) = (Ch = ' ', sum [i=1:words(IDs)] (word(Parents,i)==n ? (Ch = Ch.word(IDs,i).' ',1) : (Ch,0) ), Ch )

# m-th child of ID n
Child(n,m) = word(ChildList(n),m)

# List of leaves, recursive function
LeafList(n) = (LL='', ChildCount(n)==0 ? LL=LL.n.' ' : sum [i=1:ChildCount(n)] (LL=LL.LeafList(Child(n,i)), 0),LL)

# create list of all leaves
LeafAll = LeafList(Start(0))

# get x-position of ID n, recursive function
XPos(n) = ChildCount(n) == 0 ? ItemIdx(LeafAll,n) : (sum [i=1:ChildCount(n)] (XPos(Child(n,i))))/(ChildCount(n))

# create the tree datablock for plotting
set print $Tree
    do for [j=1:words(IDs)] {
        n = int(word(IDs,j))
        print sprintf("% 3d % 7.2f % 4d % 5s", n, XPos(n), Level(n), word(Names,j))
    }
set print
print $Tree

# get x and y distance from ID n to its parent
dx(n) = XPos(Parent(int(n))) - XPos(int(n))
dy(n) = Level(Parent(int(n))) - Level(int(n))

unset border
unset tics
set offsets 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25

plot $Tree u 2:3:(dx($1)):(dy($1)) w vec nohead ls -1 not,\
        '' u 2:3 w p pt 7 ps 6 lc rgb 0xccffcc not, \
        '' u 2:3 w p pt 6 ps 6 lw 1.5 lc rgb "black" not, \
        '' u 2:3:4 w labels offset 0,0.1 center not
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: wow thanks a lot! Last question, how can I use the code you provided in C? I should trigger this code in a C command.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how it would work with C, but basically you have to send this script as text to gnuplot and somehow get the graph in whatever format back into C.

Answer (score 0):

If we are really open for all options, may I suggest my favorite one:

```
pstree -p <pid>
or
pstree -ap <pid>
```

which may present you with something like this:

```
foo,26943 /a/b/c/foo -i...
  └─foo1,26951 /a/b/c/foo1 -x...
      └─foo2,27103 /a/b/c/foo2 -y...
```

**man pstree** -
can provide you with various options to tune what you want/don't want to see in the graph